# Controlling iTunes on iPhone from within an app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, itunes

Hi I was just wondering if there is a library or set of methods for controlling the audio playing on an iPhone, i.e. play/pause, next/prev etc.

I can't seem to find anything, does anyone know if they exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`MPMusicPlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) from the MediaPlayer framework to play "iPod" music.

```
MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
[player skipToNextItem];
//...
```